# how to call a python function and give its parameters from the command line?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

Let's say, I have a python script (test.py) and it contains a function that takes a string and printed back, as following

```
def pri(str):
    print str
```

How could i call the this function (`pri`) from the command line? 
I tried:

```
$python test.py pri(blablalba)
```

but i got the following error:
missing end of string

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.. all of them worked for me :)
though, since i am a beginner, the answers from Andy and lithiium were so clear structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sys.argv`. argv is a list of all the arguments passed through the command line.

try this:

```
import sys

def pri(s):
    print s

pri(sys.argv[1])
```

And you can run it doing `python test.py blablabla`

Answer (score 3):

You'd call the python program like any command line program:

```
python test.py blablabla
```

Then inside of the program you would do this:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

The argv variable of sys is a list of all of the arguments passed through the command line to the program that is called. So if you wanted to call specific argument numbers you would treat it like a list. If you wanted to have a method print those arguments out you would either need to pass them to the method or have the method use that variable. In your case you would want something like this:

```
import sys

def pri(str):
    print str

for each in sys.argv[1:]:
    pri(each)
```

Comment: If, in addition, `pri` should also be given on the command line, something like `locals()[argv[1]](*argv[2:])` should work.

Comment: Correct, but I think they just want something simple to pass the arguments along. If that were the case I'd suggest using something like argparse to keep track of which arguments are which and limit the methods that were called based on the flags set.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it like this (assuming your function is saved in a file named `test.py`)

```
python -c "from test import pri; pri('test')"
```

This will output the word `test`

If your file is named something other than `test.py`, substitute the word `test` in your import statement

```
>python -c "from test import pri; pri('test')"
test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print (sys.argv[1])
```

You need to use `sys.argv[1]`

If you save that in a script call pri.py

Use `python` `pri.py` `hello` from the command line and it will output `hello`

To print multiple words:

```
import sys

def pri(s):   
    print s
if __name__=="__main__":
    s = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
    pri(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would insist that you use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` construct. It allows your module to still be importable **and** to be usable from command line.

For your use case, it would be something like

```
import sys

def pri(s):
   # you stuff

# other stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test presence of params and display comprehensive errors if not applicable
    # ...
    pri(sys.argv[1])
```

That way `python test.py blabla` calls `pri('blabla')` but you can do `import test` in another python module without `pri` being automatically called.